# Use row as input to other processes in Python

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, loop

I am new to Python and need help. Looked for my answer but don't know if I am even using the correct terminology.

I have a model in which I iterated through rows and performed a set of processes on each. For example a feature class with 10 features and on each of the 10 features I wanted to create an individual feature class....or... for each row create a raster based on the field (e.g.) ID. I am trying to turn this to Python due to a host of reasons.

I am using 10.1 and the error is occurring at line 40 "FeatureClassToFeatureClass"
I believe that it is failing due to my improper use of 'row" as the input.

Here is what I have so far, but I cannot get it to work

---

```
# Import arcpy module
print "Starting...."
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
env.overwriteOutput = True

selectingfeatures = "\\\\silver\\clients\\trans1.shp"
Trans1_shp = "\\\\silver\\clients\\trans1.shp"
basecldem = "\\\\silver\\clients\\basecldem"
TEMP = "\\\\silver\\clients\\TEMP"
Zone3_shp = "\\\\silver\\clients\\Zone2.shp"
transarea = "\\\\silver\\clients\\transarea"
RegionGRP = "\\\\silver\\clients\\regiongrp"
ZonalMean = "\\\\silver\\clients\\zonalmean"
ZoneArea = "\\\\silver\\clients\\zonearea"
Transition__n_ = "\\\\silver\\clients\\transition_%n%"
I_trans1 = "I_trans1_FID"

selectingLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(selectingfeatures)
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(selectingLayer) 
#cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
#row = cursor.next()
#while row:
#    print(row.getValue(field))
for row in rows:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row, TEMP, "Zone2.shp", "", "ID \"ID\" true true false 4 Short 0 4 ,First,#,\\\\silver\\clients\\Projects\\P696\\8_BaseMine\\Processing\\TEMP\\trans1.shp,ID,-1,-1", "")
    print "Finished PFC 2 FC...."
    # Process: Polygon to Raster
    arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(Zone3_shp, "ID", ZoneArea, "CELL_CENTER", "NONE", "1")
    print "Finished Polygon to Raster...."
    # Process: Extract by Mask
    arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(basecldem, Zone3_shp, transarea)
    print "Extract by Mask...."
    # Process: Region Group
    arcpy.gp.RegionGroup_sa(ZoneArea, RegionGRP, "FOUR", "WITHIN", "ADD_LINK", "")
    print "Finished Region Group...."
    # Process: Zonal Statistics
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatistics_sa(RegionGRP, "VALUE", transarea, ZonalMean, "MEAN", "DATA")
    print "Finished Zonal Statistics...."
    # Process: Raster Calculator
    arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("If( \"%basecldem%\" > ( 0.5 + \"%ZonalMean%\" ), 0, 1 )", Transition__n_)
    print "Finished Raster Calcualtor"
    #row = cursor.next()
```

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track.  Iteration in ModelBuilder "translates" to Cursors in ArcPy.  Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  For 10.1 and later any suggestions I make would be different to 10.0.  The other key thing is to just get the iteration working on one operation (e.g. `FeatureClassToFeatureClass`) first and let us know precisely what is not working (e.g. exact error message, no output, etc, etc) from a code snippet that shows where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.getValue(field)` didn't make sense to me. Going down that path never worked out. I ended up finding something that worked:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Caribou, FCView) 
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(FCView) 
for row in cursor: 
   objectid = str(row.getValue("OBJECTID")) 
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FCView, "NEW_SELECTION", '"OBJECTID"= {}'.format(objectid)) 
   arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(FCView , TEMP, "CARIBOU", "#", FieldMappings2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is with:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(selectingLayer)
for row in rows:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row, TEMP, "Zone2.shp", "", "ID \"ID\" true true false 4 Short 0 4 ,First,#,\\\\silver\\clients\\SYNCRUDE\\Projects\\P696\\8_BaseMine\\Processing\\TEMP\\trans1.shp,ID,-1,-1", "")
```

[FeatureClassToFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000) expects as its first parameter:

> The feature class or feature layer that will be converted.

You are providing it with a row object (which you named `row`) instead.  Rather than `row`, if the name of the feature class or feature layer is being stored in a variable called `field` then use:

```
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row.getValue(field), TEMP, "Zone2.shp", "", "ID \"ID\" true true false 4 Short 0 4 ,First,#,\\\\silver\\clients\\SYNCRUDE\\Projects\\P696\\8_BaseMine\\Processing\\TEMP\\trans1.shp,ID,-1,-1", "")
```

but be aware that your code does not set the variable `field` anywhere that I can see.

Depending on how you are setting `field` you may need to be aware that ListFields returns a list of field objects rather than field names so `field.name` may be needed.

Comment: Sorry @polygeo, very new to Python... I have a featurelayer called selectingLayer as defined above. 

Do I just put: for row in rows:
    
`arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row.getValue(selectingLayer), TEMP, "Zone2.shp", "", "ID \"ID\" true true false 4 Short 0 4 ,First,#,\\\\silver\\clients\\SYNCRUDE\\Projects\\P696\\8_BaseMine\\Processing\\TEMP\\trans‌​1.shp,ID,-1,-1", "")`

Comment: Because you are new to Python I think you should take a step back from the question you are asking here, which I think I have answered, and instead aim for a better understanding of how cursors work first.  Try writing some test code that adapts the first example at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000070000000 to your own data and when that makes sense come back and see whether my answer becomes more understandable.

Comment: W.r.t. your previous comment `selectingLayer` is a layer object, and `row.getValue()` is expecting a field name so that code will inevitably error.  If that code comes from exporting a model to a Python script then I think you would do better to start from a new script and just copy a line at a time into it, testing frequently, and making sure you understand what each does and why any errors you see occur.

Comment: Valid points. Frustrated with modelbuilder so trying to make a fast switch to python using iterators. I will follow your advice.